# Example for "core programming" and how to do it?

Tags: architecture

The only thing I know for sure is it has nothing with threads or CPU cores.
It is supposed to be approach to create application with no/minimal dependencies so "logic" would be independent from used framework and would remain unchanged, when switching libraries/frameworks.

I have unintentionally eavesdropped on conversation about this, so I am not sure, if I have understood it all correctly.
It sounds good, but I haven't seen any example of this approach and would have no idea how to try it.

Did I understood it right?
What is (nontrivial) example of core programming?
What should I watch out when applying it to my (probably new) projects?

EDIT:
I have done extensive research and I think I may have found something.
It looks like it may have something to do with "Clean Architecture" by "Uncle Bob".

https://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html

[image]

I have seen somewhere phrase like "everything depends on the core, but core depends on nothing".

I still would like to see some real world example (or at least something bigger than hello world).
I am especially interested in:

1. Where (in which circle) will application boot?
   It cannot be core if I would like to use ex. Spring Boot, that would be probably in some outer ring - how to boot application?
2. How (who - which ring) to handle requests? Again, it cannot be core, as as it is pure logic it has nothing to do with accepting user data (if I understand it right, that is)
3. How will crons proceed? Who will invoke them?

Sorry for messy question - "to ask good question You need to already know half of the answer" - which I don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "core programming" is sometimes used in the sense of using the basic features of a programming language exclusively as opposed to using specific libraries or frameworks.

This is something that mostly makes sense in an educational context. An example would be implementing your own linked list. Most languages have linked list implementations in their standard libraries and these are probably much better than anything you would implement yourself. Still it is a great exercise to do something like this on your own.

In a "real" project however, you are probably better off using existing code.

Comment: Many thanks for Your answer, but I am sure that's not it. Please see my edited question for new information.

Comment: @xinus01: Never heard this in the context of "Clean Architecture". Also, in the links you added, I could not find the term "Core Programming".

Comment: @xinus01 : Could it be that you actually mean "Kernel Programming"?

Comment: I am afraid it's not about kernel too. I start to think, that they have created this term on-the-fly or I must have misheard/misunderstood conversation without wider context. Anyway, much thanks for help.